# How do i line input-groups up with form-groups in bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I've had a look all around google and SO cant seem to find a solution for this.

What i'm trying to do is align an input-group with all my other form-groups. Every time i use an input-group it adds like a padding to it.

I've tried almost every answer I've found on here:

```
padding:0px !important;
margin:0px !important;
float: left !important;
```

Nothing seems to work!

Code:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input id="est_mileage" name="est_mileage" type="text" placeholder="Estimated Mileage" autocomplete="off" class="form-control input-md"/>
                </div>
                <!--Padding Issue is Here-->
                <div class="input-group" style="padding:0px !important; margin:0px !important; float:left; width:100%;">
                  <span class="input-group-addon" style="width: 45px;">
                    <input value="1" type="checkbox" id="combinedSelector" name="one_off" />
                  </span>
                <input id="acc_mileage" name="acc_mileage" type="text" placeholder="Actual Mileage" autocomplete="off" class="form-control"/>
                </div>
                <!--End Issue-->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input id="fuel" name="fuel" type="text" placeholder="Fuel(ltrs)" autocomplete="off" class="form-control input-md"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input id="price" name="price" type="text" placeholder="Price" autocomplete="off" class="form-control input-md" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input id="cwt_dwt" name="cwt_dwt" type="text" placeholder="CWT & DWT" autocomplete="off" class="form-control input-md" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input id="def_ser_num" name="def_ser_num" type="text" placeholder="Defect Serial Number" autocomplete="off" class="form-control input-md" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input required id="product_volume" name="product_volume" type="text" placeholder="Product Volume" autocomplete="off" class="form-control input-md" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input id="ref_po" name="ref_po" type="text" placeholder="Ref/PO" autocomplete="off" class="form-control input-md" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input id="comments" name="comments" type="text" placeholder="Job Specifics" autocomplete="off" class="form-control input-md" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input id="billing_com" name="billing_com" type="text" placeholder="Billing Info" autocomplete="off" class="form-control input-md" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input id="iss_rep" name="iss_rep" type="text" placeholder="Issues/Repairs" autocomplete="off" class="form-control input-md" />
                </div>
            </div>
```

This form is nested in a collapse div and is in a modal view.

This is the result:
[image: Padding Issue Image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add the class **form-group** to div with **input-group** class and remove the styles: `padding:0px !important; margin:0px !important; float:left;`

and this will make it similar to the other form groups

[**See Demo Here**](http://www.bootply.com/IvafVC6lo1)

Comment: Thats worked! So simple don't know how I missed that one. Thank You

Comment: i'm glad it helped :)